# Change tax percent in magento 1.8

Tags: php, magento-1.8

In `app/code/local/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Subtotal.php`,
`_totalBaseCalculation` has a function where it sets tax percent,
`$item->setTaxPercent($rate)`.

However I wish to set tax percent to `(rate +y(any number))`.
When I do this, there is no change in quote item data in `sales_flat_quote_item`. Is tax percent inserted from somewhere else???

Comment: you should move your question, here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Chester is correct, this should be migrated.  Also, it looks like you can do this through Tax Rules/Rates in the Magento Admin area.  The [Magento User Guide](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/Resources/pdf/magento_community_edition_user_guide.pdf) gives a pretty good explaination.  `Chapter 54: Managing Taxes` starts on `page 753`

Answer (score 0):

Simply set tax rates of your wish in Backend at

```
Sales->Tax->Manage Tax Rates
```